# DRF options request on viewset with multiple serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using a mixin on my viewset so that multiple serializers can be used accross different [viewset actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) and any [custom actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions).

I have an extra action called `invoice` which is just a normal update but using a different serializer. I need to perform an OPTIONS request at the endpoint to get options for a `<select>` element. The problem is that when I perform the request it's picking up the serializer from the default update - `OrderSerializer` instead of `InvoiceSerializer`. How can I pick up the options from the correct serializer?

```
class MultipleSerializerMixin:
    """
    Mixin that allows for multiple serializers based on the view's
    `serializer_action_classes` attribute.

    ex.
        serializer_action_classes = {
            'list': ReadOnlyListSerializer,
            'retrieve': ReadOnlyDetailSerializer,
        }
    """
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        try:
            return self.serializer_action_classes[self.action]
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            return super().get_serializer_class()


class OrderAPIViewSet(MultipleSerializerMixin,
                      viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.OrderSerializer
    serializer_action_classes = {
        'invoice': serializers.InvoiceSerializer,
    }

    @action(detail=True, methods=['put'], url_name='invoice')
    def invoice(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Invoice the order and order lines.
        """
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Update:**

So after inspecting the [`determine_actions` method in `metadata.SimpleMetadata`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/335054a5d36b352a58286b303b608b6bf48152f8/rest_framework/metadata.py#L73) it would seem that when performing an OPTIONS request `view.action` is `metadata` instead of `invoice` which explains why the serializer is defaulting to `view.serializer_class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to create an [extra action as a schema endpoint](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#creating-schema-endpoints) that could be accessed via a GET request that manually sets the action to `invoice`.

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get', 'put'])
def invoice_schema(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.action = 'invoice'
    data = self.metadata_class().determine_metadata(request, self)
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

A more DRY solution if you have multiple actions that use different serializers would be to override the view's `options` method and set the action from the query parameters. This could be added to `MultipleSerializerMixin` to make it the default behaviour for all views that use this mixin.

```
def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.action = request.query_params.get('action')
    return super().options(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `get_serializer_class` method is enough and OPTIONS request will detect which serializer to use :

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
   if self.request.method == 'GET':
      return ReadOnlyShopSerializer
   return ShopSerializer
```